# applying for permissions other than basic for instagram

Tags: android, permissions, instagram

I am working on an application for Samsung Gear watch to access Instagram and display user's photos and photos from people they follow.
2 days ago I was able to apply for permissions other than basic, such as follower-list and public_content. However today I don't see any possibility to apply for additional permissions.
Instead, I read "We no longer offer additional permissions to new applications using the legacy API."

is  this a known change ? Did they make it just today ?
Where else can I apply for this kind of permission if I believe that my app is worth it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been replaced by the [Instagram Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram).

Comment: what do you mean ? is this type of access/permissions available on the new platform ? who can use it ?

Comment: but I am not building apps for Instagram Business Accounts. I am interested in developing an app for Instagram users to see their follower photos on platforms that do not yet have an Instagram client.